# JasperReports API: getting error when calling report view method by different jar

Tags: java, jasper-reports

My application based on several *jar* files: login.jar, mainform.jar, reportview.jar.
The login jar calls mainform.jar and it'll call report view.jar likewise.

So in reportview class i have a method for showing report with *JasperViewer*:

```
reportSource = Reportpath + getReportname() + ".jasper";

HashMap para = new HashMap();
para.put(getReport_param1(), getParam1());
para.put(getReport_param2(), getParam2());
para.put(getReport_param3(), getParam3());
para.put(getReport_param4(), getParam4());
para.put(getReport_param5(), getParam5());

JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportSource, para, con);

JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);
```

So as single project its run 100% correctly and view report.

But when i'm import this class to mainform and call reportview method it didn't run. I used 
*jasperreports-3.1.4.jar* file for *JasperReports* library. It work fine when calls report module by its main methos.
But when calling from different jar it gives this error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseTextField to field net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseLineBox.boxContainer of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRBoxContainer in instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseLineBox
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2032)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1212)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1953)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:85)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObjectFromLocation(JRLoader.java:244)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:316)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:275)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:399)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:1300)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:631)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:228)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:730)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:632)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:63)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:402)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:234)
>       at reportmodule.Reportmodule.getReport(Reportmodule.java:329)
>       at Login.Login$7.run(Login.java:344)

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please help me..
Tell me if you guys need any clarification.

Comment: Finally I found error.
Its because of some other project(mainform.jar) is import old version jasper library(1.2).
removing that library from mainform solved my problem.
Thanks all for view my problem.

Comment: You can post this comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found error. Its because of some other project(mainform.jar) is import old version jasper library(1.2). removing that library from mainform solved my problem.